How to add a placeholder in MUI Select component if value prop & option of MenuItem are different?
I want to add a placeholder (-- Select --) to the following MUI Select component.
const [country, setCountry] = useState("")
<FormControl fullWidth error={!country}>
    <Select
        displayEmpty
        renderValue={selected => selected.length === 0 ? '-- Select --' : selected}
        value={country}
        onChange={e => setCountry(e.target.value)}
    >
        <MenuItem value='US'>America</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value='CA'>Canada</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value='UK'>England</MenuItem>
    </Select>
    {!country && <FormHelperText>This field is required.</FormHelperText>}
</FormControl>

When I added displayEmpty and following renderValue prop to the Select component, if I selected 'America', 'US' instead of 'America' was rendered.
renderValue={selected => selected.length === 0 ? '-- Select --' : selected}
If value props were changed like following, the component worked.
<MenuItem value='America'>America</MenuItem>
<MenuItem value='Canada'>Canada</MenuItem>
<MenuItem value='England'>England</MenuItem>

However, only country codes will be stored in database, so values must be 'US', 'CA' and 'UK'. Could someone teach me how to add a placeholder while the corresponding option can be correctly shown when it's selected?

The most common and the recommended way to do this is by finding the correct label in your object.
There must be an array of countries through which you are getting the list. (If not please create one)
You should have both id and label for each country. And when any country is selected (selected length is not 0), try to find that country with id in that list and display its label.
const CountryFormComponent = () => {

...rest of component body

const listOfCountries = [{id : 'US', label: 'America'},
{id : 'CA', label: 'Canada'},
{id : 'UK', label: 'England'},
];


const generateRenderValue = (selected) => {
return (selected.length === 0 ? '-- Select --' : listOfCountries.find((x) => x.id === selected).label);
}



....
//return statement
....
<FormControl fullWidth error={!country}>
    <Select
        displayEmpty
        renderValue={generateRenderValue}
        value={country}
        onChange={e => setCountry(e.target.value)}
    >
        {listOfCountries.map((x) => <MenuItem value={x.id}>{x.label}</MenuItem>}
    </Select>

